# Stopping the services started by pending intent

Tags: android, service, android-pendingintent

I am using location services for obtaining the location updates.

I am starting a service by passing a pending intent like below

```
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!isMyServiceRunning()) {
                mIntentService = new Intent(StartOrStopService.this,
                        LocationServices.class);
                mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( 
                        StartOrStopService.this, 1, mIntentService, 0);

                locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationrequest.setInterval(1000*60);
                locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest,
                        mPendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(StartOrStopService.this, "Starting Service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else
                Toast.makeText(StartOrStopService.this,
                        "Service already running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

        }
    });
```

The above code works fine and starts the service on a click of a button.

Also I have one more button , which i am using to stop the service ,started by pending intent and below is what i have tried

```
   btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isMyServiceRunning()) {
                StartOrStopService.this.stopService(new Intent(StartOrStopService.this,
                        LocationServices.class));
                Toast.makeText(StartOrStopService.this,
                        "Stopping service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Stop service");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StartOrStopService.this,
                        "No Services are running presently",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

But I am unable to stop the service. Can some one please suggest me what's the mistake i am doing. Also suggest me some suggestion??..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check this http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/introduction-to-services-in-android.html#.U1n-V_mSweE

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't mean that you want to stop the service. I assume you mean you want to stop having the location client start your service. To do that, you just need to call `removeLocationUpdates()` and pass the same `PendingIntent` you used when you starting requesting location updates:

```
    mIntentService = new Intent(StartOrStopService.this, LocationServices.class);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(StartOrStopService.this, 1,
                                  mIntentService, 0);

    locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be that the service has been designed to be stopped via an intent command. So, you should modify your LocationServices class to handle such a "special intent".

Comment: can you please explain how to do that?. Thanks :)

Comment: your service should override onCreate (or onStartCommand for an IntentService) and, if a special argument is present in the extras of the intent, then it stops.